# How to pass enum value into @Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, .net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I have some method

```
public ActionResult ExportToCSV(CellSeparators cellSeparator)
{
  //
}          

public enum CellSeparators
{
   Semicolon,
   Comma
}
```

How we can refer to that method correctly in html?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Exportar al CSV", "ExportToCSV", new { ?? })
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Html.ActionLink("Exportar al CSV", "ExportToCSV", new { **cellSeparator=(int)CellSeparators.Semicolon** })

And

```
public ActionResult ExportToCSV(int cellSeparator)
{
  CellSeparator separator = (CellSeparator)cellSeparator;
}
```

Is not elegant, but is usefull

Comment: Also RouteValueDictionary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976371/pass-collection-of-enums-to-asp-net-mvc-actionmethod

Answer (score 3):

Into your View.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Exportar al CSV", "ExportToCSV", new { cellSeparator=CellSeparators.Semicolon })
```

Into your Controller:

```
public ActionResult ExportToCSV(CellSeparators? cellSeparator)
{
  if(cellSeparator.HasValue)
  {
    CellSeparator separator = cellSeparator.Value;
  }

  /* ... */
}
```